# C# Inheritance Problem

Tags: c#, inheritance

Let's say I have 3 classes:

GrandDad, Dad and Son. Son inherits from Dad, which inherits from GrandDad.

GrandDad has 2 methods:

```
public virtual void foo();
public virtual void do();
```

Dad inherits foo(), but overrides do();

```
public override void do();
```

If Son wants to modify foo(), is it acceptable to:

make Dad override foo(), but simply call foo.base()? Then Son can override foo(), but Dad's foo() functionality remains the same?

Or is that a hacky way?

Comment: On a side note, inheritance isn't a good model for this kind of relationship, as a Son isn't always a kind of Dad and a Dad isn't always a kind of GrandDad.  These concepts are more 'ownership' relationships than 'is a' relationships and are better modeled with composition via references between classes or in an overall FamilyTree.  Human inheritance is not really analogous to class inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as `Dad` never defined a `foo()`, there's no reason he has to do anything. `Son` should be able to override `foo()` from `GrandDad`.

Answer (score 2):

`Dad` doesn't have to override `foo()`. Since `Dad` simply inherits the version supplied by `Granddad` (which is still `virtual`), that means that's what `Son` gets, too, allowing `Son` to override `foo()`.

```
public class Granddad {
    public virtual void foo() {...}
    public virtual void do() {...}
}

public class Dad {
    public override void do() {...}
}

public class Son {
    public override void foo() {...}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it needs to be declared override and virtual?

Comment: @Kevin: That was actually incorrect on my part. Once declared `virtual` on the base class, it is overridable in all deriving classes. You actually get a compile error if you try to declare both.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question, there's no need to do anything with Dad. Simply implement foo() within Son.

As Son is a descendant from Dad, nothing within Son changes Dad, so if Son implements foo(), Dad's foo() remains the same, inheriting from GrandDad.

Answer (score 1):

The semantics of the problem may have lead you astray.

If you are REALLY doing Father, Son, Grandfather...

You only need one class:  Person.  It will have a member property called Father that will point to another Person.  This way, you can have many generations instead of being locked in at three.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by modify `foo`? If you mean override, then Son can simply override `foo()`. No need to make Dad override `foo()` calling base implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Dad doesn't need to override Foo for Son to override Foo.  Foo is virtual all the way up the inheritance chain unless someone overrides it AND declares it sealed.